# how can I use loop for store multiple travelers information?

Tags: node.js

I want to store multiple travelers information. I am using Amadeus NodeJS sdk. whenever I used loop, a client error appears. please guide me how I can store multiples travelers information.

here is my code

````json
```JSON.stringify({
              'data':{
                'type': 'flight-order',
                'flightOffers': [response.data.flightOffers[0]],            
               'travelers':[{
                  "id": i++,
                  "name": {
                    "firstName": req.body.firstname,
                    "lastName": req.body.lastname
                  },
                  "gender": req.body.gender,
                  "contact": {
                    "emailAddress": req.body.emailaddress,
                    "phones": [{
                      "deviceType": req.body.devicetype,
                      "countryCallingCode": req.body.countrycallingcode,
                      "number": req.body.number
                    }]
                  },
                  "documents": [{
                    "documentType": req.body.documentype,
                    "birthPlace": req.body.birthplace,
                    "issuanceLocation": req.body.issuancelocation,
                    "issuanceDate": req.body.issuancedate,
                    "number": req.body.p_number,
                    "expiryDate": req.body.expirydate,
                    "issuanceCountry": req.body.issuancecountry,
                    "validityCountry": req.body.validitycountry,
                    "nationality": req.body.nationality,
                    "holder": true
                  }]
                }
              ]
            } 
          })```
````

Comment: "_whenever I used loop I client error appear_" this is not a problem description. show what code you tried and quote the error in full.

Comment: here is error: (node:7644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<ClientError>
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode)

Comment: i want to store multiple travelers iformation like in formats:                                       "travelers": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
        "name": {
          "firstName": "JORGE",
          "lastName": "GONZALES"
        },
        "gender": "MALE",
        "contact": {
          "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es",
          "phones": [
            {
              "deviceType": "MOBILE",
              "countryCallingCode": "34",
              "number": "480080076"
            }
          ]
        },
      },